# How to handle JSON data in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I use Laravel as tool for building RESTful application.

There is an end-point `/settings/update` that takes JSON of user settings.

I send to this address data in JSON format.

How to handle this data in `Request $request?`

So, I can not refer to property as: `$request->notifications`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sent as JSON, the `Request` factory will allow you to access properties of that object.

Given a JSON object passed like this:

```
{ 
    "user" : {
         "settings" : {
             "some_setting" : {
                 "value" : 'My value'
             }
         }
    }

}
```

You can access the `value` using dot notation:

```
$request->input('user.settings.some_setting.value');
```